# strategy for making an iframe responsive within a php page

Tags: php, css

I am attempting to make a form which is using an iframe and the surrounding web page responsive using css media queries.
The php page has several css style sheets in different places, and I have modified them using css3 media queries.

The iframe content is coming from a php template.
There are other php pages that impact the page I am trying to make responsive.

When I try to make the iframe php template responsive on the back end, the iframe
is minimally modified.

The closest I have come to making the iframe responsive is by modifying the various css pages,
and using something like the following on the iframe (I am doing this from memory because i am not on my machine at work):

```
      iframe{
         width:100%;
         display:block;
         position:absolute;
       }
```

for some reason, it was responding to this in the css, but when I try to put this piece of code in the php template it does not work.

btw the template is using a mixture of divs and tables.

what a mess...

There are global php files as well, and I think I have tracked them down.

I know this is a lot, but my questions are as follows:

1. Should I continue working on the form template by putting media queries in this page alone and see if the form responds?
2. Should I also continue working the various css pages?

Does anyone know of a simpler solution or solutions that do not involve importing massive libraries or making this overly complicated?

Remember keep it simple? Well things seem to be moving far away from that...

So, I have modified the template form to make it responsive using media queries and divs. It is responsive on the back end. However, the front end with the iframe is not responding. Here is part of the code on the front end:

```
    <style>
      @media screen and (max-width:500px){

                           #tab1 #wrapper #contentWrapper #sub6 #content #textBackground          #textWrapper{
                            display:block;
                            width:100%;
                            height:auto;
                        } 

                     #tab1 #wrapper #contentWrapper #sub6 #content #textBackground #embed-container{
                       position:relative;
                       padding-bottom:56.25%;
                       padding-top:30px;
                       height:0;

                   }
                 #tab1 #wrapper #contentWrapper #sub6 #content #textBackground  #embed-container iframe{
                       position:absolute;
                       top:0;
                       left:0;
                       width:100%;
                       height:100%;
                   }
                </style>

         <body id="tab1">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contentWrapper">
    <?php require('includes/banner.htm'); ?>
    <?php require('includes/navigation.htm'); ?>
    <div id="sub6">
    <?php require('includes/commercialNav.htm'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="textBackground" style="border-top: solid 1px #f1f2f1;">

    <div id="textWrapper" >
    <div id="embed-container" style="margin: 0 auto;">


            <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="max-width:2500px;min-width:250px;max-height:1200px;min-height:800px;" frameborder="0" src="<?php print($contact_form_url); ?>"></iframe>
     <br>
</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php require('includes/sitefooter.htm'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The iframe is not responding to the css. If i take away the inline style, the template form does not show at all.  There are no cross domain issues.

```
Regards,
```

umbre gachoong

Comment: `position: absolute` and tables (with fixed widths in pixels I guess) aren't exactly suited for adaptiveness to the width of the viewport... Can't say more without seeing a simplified page and code that reproduces your problem. EDIT: browsers don't care about PHP. They receive HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: We need more. It would appear as the iframe is 100% width of the nearest relatively positioned parent. Please provide more CSS details.

Comment: the form in question is here http://recologyamericancanyon.com/contact.php

Comment: ok, so i tracked down all the classes governing a specific element i needed to modify. There were several css style sheets, and I wrapped each of the classes in various media queries. I converted the old school php pages to html5, and used the meta tags for viewports.  It is a lot of work. So far everything responds in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 and 10. I used css3-mediaqueries.js for IE8 but so far I am having to tweak some of the css there.You can delete this if you want, but it may be useful for someone who is trying to convert old school legacy pages and make them responsive.